# assertIsInstance() against multiple class names

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a function which should set an object attribute to a PIL Image instance:

```
from PIL import Image

class SimpleExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = self.load_image()

    def load_image():
        self.img = Image.open(image)
```

To test the proper execution of load_image() I thought to use unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance(), but introspection of the resultant instance gives a different **class**.**name** depending on the file type of the image that was loaded. I can't find anything along the lines of *assertIsInstanceFromModule()* in unittest, so this seems to be the assertion helper that best reflects what I am really trying to test.

I have come up with a couple solutions but am not satisfied with either of them:

**Use a loop**
Produce a list of all possible class names, iterate though list, test each member for equality, then assertIsInstance for the appropriate list member. This is awkward, unpythonic, and I'm certainly not very proud of it. It does however work, and it uses what I think is the most meaningful assertion.

```
simplified_names = ['JpegImageFile', 'PngImageFile']
for i, name in enumerate(simplified_names):
    if SimpleExample.img.__class__.__name__ == name:
        TestCase.assertIsInstance(SimpleExample.img, simplified_names[i])
```

**Use a different assertion helper**
Produce a list of all possible class names and assert that the class name of the generated object is in that list. It works, it's simple, but I don't like what it is that I'm actually asserting here.

```
simplified_names = ['JpegImageFile', 'PngImageFile']
TestCase.assertIn(SimpleExample.img.__class__.__name__, simplified_names)
```

Does anyone have any other idea about how to assert against multiple possible class names?
Should I be approaching the test from a different direction and use a different assertion?
This is my first foray into unittest. Should I go back to just testing my code with print?

~~~~~
And the obvious answer is...

Test against parent class. Alternatively, I could have noticed that a better option was presented to me every time I saw the following error:

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Emphasis on the "or tuple."

Thanks for all the help Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the *parent class*; you don't care which one of the many subclasses this is, just if it is an image file.

The second argument of `assertIsInstace()` must be the class itself, not a class name:

```
from PIL import ImageFile

self.assertIsInstance(SimpleExample.img, ImageFile.ImageFile)
```

or you could go one step further up and assert that it is a `PIL.Image.Image` instance, and not care if it came from a specific file or was produced otherwise:

```
from PIL import Image

self.assertIsInstance(SimpleExample.img, Image.Image)
```

If you do ever need to test against multiple classes, `isinstance()` (and by extension, `assertIsInstance()`) also accepts a tuple of classes as the second argument:

```
>>> foo = 'bar'
>>> isinstance(foo, (str, int, float))
True
```

Comment: If I try this: `assertIsInstance(img, PIL)` it throws a type error: `TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`

Am I misunderstanding what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Jefe: I included a sample test.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you. Can you explain real quick how I should have found the correct parent class name? I checked .__class__ on an instance of the object I'm looking at, and that was obviously not right.

Comment: @Jefe: I looked at the source code real quick here; the documentation is unfortunately rather lacking in that point. Classes have a `.__bases__` attribute that is a tuple of the direct base classes, or you can use `.__mro__` for all classes in method-resolution order.